# Value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Tags: swift

I started a Swift project with Xcode 6 Beta 6. The project was also using Core Data. After upgrading to Xcode 6 GM, I am getting the following error when compiling:

```
/Users/.../AppDelegate.swift:58:52: Value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

The line of code for the error is:

```
return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
```

Any idea what changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I just unwrapped the optional using `'!'` and the code is compiling now.

`return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)`